# OpenCV UDP source specific multicast

Tags: python, opencv, udp, streaming, multicast

I'm trying to make an alert script to get emails when a channel is down!
I wrote this simple code and it worked. However, OpenCV doesn't lock UDP source specific multicast.

It is working only with the streams without source specific, for example 'udp://239.1.1.1:111' . The network is configured that way that only with SSM you'll receive the multicast, like this: 'udp://10.20.30.40@239.1.1.1:1111'

this is the code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://10.20.30.40@239.1.1.1:1111')
if(cap.isOpened()==True):
  server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, message1)
else:
  (cap.isOpened()==False)
  server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, message2)
  
server.quit()
```

I'm expecting anyone to help me with this.

Thank you